# Android Unit test method that content CountDownTimer class

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, android-testing

**Problem**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method start in android.os.CountDownTimer not mocked.

even though that i have mock it already.

> Here is my code

```
           void mSomething() {
                new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        //do somethig
                    }
    }.start();
}
```

> Here is my Test

```
@Test
     public void testSomething() throws Exception {

     CountDownTimer countDownTimer = mock(CountDownTimer.class);
     PowerMockito.whenNew(CountDownTimer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(countDownTimer);

    someClass.mSomething();
    //verify
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have in your `@PrepareForTest` annotation--that's a common source of bugs in PowerMock.

Comment: @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(someClass.class)

Comment: You're not preparing `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: i had try that as well and still getting the same error

Comment: @MohammedAsmar Did you manage to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

add this line to module **build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    } }
```

this code solved my problem

Comment: It worked, thank you @mohsen!